# Fallback to png using the "use" tag

Tags: html, angular, svg

there are some issues displaying SVGs for older IE versions. My question is then: *is there a way to fallback to a png while using the "use" tag?*

I am using Angular 2, so if could be solved using this framework, that would also be OK. Doing it in the HTML **is preferred**.

Below is the code for displaying the SVG.

```
<svg class="logo" viewBox="0 0 70 70" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
  <use [attr.xlink:href]="logoPath" (error)="useDefaultImage()"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not use the  tag at all. Replaced it with inline SVG.